# Socket.broadcast calling sender too

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use sockets to send coordinates on mouse events. Everything works fine, but the socket.broadcast triggers the sender too. I assume socket.broadcast is not supposed to call himself too, but somehow it happens here.

Here is my client side emit

```
ball.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var coords = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
    socket.emit('ballMouseDown', coords);
}
```

My server side, everything works fine here

```
socket.on('ballMouseDown', function (coords) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('ballMouseDown', coords);
});
```

And my client side again

[EDIT]
This following snippet is located in a separated public JS file. If I put it in the index.html file, the broadcast works fine.

```
socket.on('ballMouseDown', function(coords){
    // fired in the sender's console too
    console.log(coords);
})
```

The coords appears in the other users console as expected, but it is also in the sender's one, fired by the same line in the `socket.on` listener.

I have a message event in those files, triggered on client side with a form submit button, and here the socket.broadcast works fine. The mouse event could be the problem, but I haven't found anything related to this yet.

Comment: `Flag:’ broadcast ' - Sets a modifier for a subquent events emission that the event data will only be broadcast to every sockets but the sender.` Look for error

Comment: Try to comment out a line with broadcast and try again - will the sender have a message?

Comment: No, I just tried it, the console is empty. The message is from `console.log(coords)` on client side for everyone.

Comment: how you get `socket` var? From "on connect" callback?

Comment: Yes, `io.on('connection', function (socket) { // code })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is not the separated file, it is the way I call it. If I put the `<script src="js/draganddrop.js"></script>` at the end of my index.html file, it works as expected. I think it is about loading time, because nothing really needed to be call before the file.

So this solved my problem. Hope it helps someone.